# Display Post from Custom Post Type with Shortcode

Tags: posts, shortcode, customization

I've created a custom post type for locations on my site and I would like to display each post in full with shortcode. I'm quite new to creating shortcode and I'm struggling to wrap my head around it. I want to display the post by slug like this: [stefan_location slug="Aspley"] but I can't get it to work. I know I'm probably way off so any advise would be welcome!!

```
function cpt_content_func($atts){
    $post = '';
    $content = '';
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'slug' => null,
    ), $atts ) );
    $args = array(
        'name' => $slug,
        'post_type' => 'location',
        'numberposts' => 1
    );
    $post = get_posts( $args );
    if ( !empty( $post ) ) {
        $content = $post[0]->post_content;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode('stefan_location','stefan_location');
```

Comment: Well, the second parameter for your `add_shortcode()` should be `cpt_content_func`.

Answer (score 0):

- You enter second parameter in add shorcode is incorrect,you missing callable function in parameter.
- Like below this add_shortcode with parameter.

> add_shortcode( string $tag, callable $callback );

Code :

```
function cpt_content_func($atts){
    $post = '';
    $content = '';
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'slug' => null,
    ), $atts ) );
    $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'location', 
          'posts_per_page' => 1, 
          'post_name__in' => $atts['slug'] ); 

    $post = get_posts( $args );
    if ( !empty( $post ) ) {
        $content = $post[0]->post_content;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode('stefan_location','cpt_content_func');
```

Comment: thanks I've changed this now and it's recognising the shortcode now but I think the attributes are still off as it's not displaying the post at all can you see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You can change your argument like this$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'location',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_name__in'  => $atts['slug']
);